# How to use Microsoft Fakes framework to shim an instance method?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, microsoft-fakes

I am using Microsoft Fakes framework within VS2012.

I use the following code to shim **instance** methods of my type.

```
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimDateTime.NowGet = () => { return new DateTime(1949, 10, 1); };
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;  // shim works for the static property DateTime.Now.

        Class1 dependency = new Class1();


        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimClass1 shim1 = new ShimClass1();
            StubClass1 stub1 = new StubClass1();
            shim1.method1 = () => { return "shim method1"; };
            shim1.IMethod1 = () => { return "shim IMethod1"; };

            String s1 = dependency.method1();// shim doesn't work for the instance method.
            String s2 = dependency.IMethod1();// shim doesn't work for the instance method.
        }
```

The class1 and looks like this:

```
public class Class1 : Interface1
{
    public String method1()
    {
        return "real method1";
    }

    //Interface 1 member
    public string IMethod1()
    {
        return "real IMethod1";
    }
}
```

I expect the s1 and s2 to be the shimed output, but it is still real output.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If 'method1' was static your shim would have worked. However with the current code you have not really shimmed out 'method1'. You need to either associate the instance with the shim instance

> Class1 dependency  = new ShimClass1() { Method1 = () => { return "Shim.Method1"; } };

or associate all instance methods with your delegate

> ShimClass1.AllInstances.Method1 = (q)=> { return "Shim.Method1"; };

Also I dont see the need to have the ShimsContext.Create() done twice

If you want to use stubs to redirect IMethod1 you should be consuming the StubInterface1 instead

> Class1 dependency = new StubInterface1() { Method1 = () { return ""; } };

Variations of these are available on msdn for reference