# How to write update type unit test by using Shim with Microsoft Fakes

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, shim

I'm new to Shim and Microsoft Fakes. I have been using Shim for unit test for Get() method. However, I'm confused about how to use it for Update() method. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Example codes:

```
public static class Application
{
    public static void SubmitApplication(Models.Application app)
    {
        var o = Order.NewOrder();
        o.id = app.id;
        o.price = app.price;
        ...
        ...
        o.SaveOrder();
    }
}
```

Test project:
For the GetApplication(Id) unit test, we have a CreateTestData() method to read the test data from xml file like below:

```
public DataSet CreateTestData(string DataFile = "")
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        if (DataFile == "")
        {
            ds.ReadXml($@"{Path.GetFullPath(".")}\application.xml");
        }
        else
        {
            ds.ReadXml($@"{Path.GetFullPath(".")}\" + DataFile + ".xml");
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

and then use ShimContext to test GetApplication(id) method.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@".\Data\application.xml")]
    public void GetApplication()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            //Arrange
            SqlCommon.ShimSqlObjects();
            SqlCommon.ShimDbAdapter(CreateTestData());

            var result = Application.GetApplication(1)
            ......
        }
    }
```

And now I'm confused how to use fake data for Update, which is my method SubmitApplication().

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@".\Data\applicationToSubmit")]
    public void CIMS_Interop_SubmitApplication()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            //Arrange
            SqlCommon.ShimSqlObjects();
            SqlCommon.ShimDbAdapter(CreateTestData("applicationToSubmit"));

            //???
        }
    }
```

I want to fake the data that pass into the method ("applicationToSubmit.xml"). Is that possible to read from an xml file to fake the parameter? And more importantly how to test the result whether the application has been save or not? If it's fake data, where the data save to? to an xml file?

Thanks!

Comment: Many would argue you should never mock all the way down to the data adapter. You should wrap your data access in a Repository and then you can mock easily. If you want to exercise your actual data access code then that is an integration test and you will be hitting the database for real.

Comment: Well, some of our projects have repository, unfortunately this one doesn't and we probably won't change it to repository in a short time. And Shim and Microsoft Fakes are thenmethods we currently use to mock data. I need to find a way to test Update by using Shim. Testing Select by Shim seems staightforward but update is a puzzle to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Microsoft Fakes framework to shim an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539563/how-to-use-microsoft-fakes-framework-to-shim-an-instance-method)